# Can't create foreign key constrain in MySQL in table creation, but the syntax it's same as others foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am currently struggling to comprehend why the first MySQL code does not work for the position foreign key. Meanwhile, when I add the backtick to Position it allows the creation of the table.

I had searched if Position is a reserved word for MySQL and could not find any mention of it being a reserved word.

So I was wondering if anybody knows why it does not work.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    IDEmployee INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
    IDPosition INT NOT NULL,
    IDPerson INT NOT NULL,
    EmployeeNumber VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IDEmployee),
    FOREIGN KEY (IDPosition) REFERENCES Position(IDPosition),
    FOREIGN KEY (IDPerson) REFERENCES Person(IDPerson)
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    IDEmployee INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
    IDPosition INT NOT NULL,
    IDPerson INT NOT NULL,
    EmployeeNumber VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IDEmployee),
    FOREIGN KEY (IDPosition) REFERENCES `Position`(IDPosition),
    FOREIGN KEY (IDPerson) REFERENCES Person(IDPerson)
);
```

Comment: You defined the table with backticks.  Don't do that.  It just makes writing SQL code that much trickier.

Comment: [Position()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position) is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Employee (
    ->     IDEmployee INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
    ->     IDPosition INT NOT NULL,
    ->     IDPerson INT NOT NULL,
    ->     EmployeeNumber VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ->     Username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ->     Password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (IDEmployee),
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (IDPosition) REFERENCES Position(IDPosition),
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (IDPerson) REFERENCES Person(IDPerson)
    -> );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Position(IDPosition),
    FOREIGN KEY (IDPerson) REFERENCES Person(IDPerson)
)' at line 9
```

This error is because [POSITION()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position) is a function.

```
mysql> help position;
Name: 'POSITION'
Description:
Syntax:
POSITION(substr IN str)

POSITION(substr IN str) is a synonym for LOCATE(substr,str).

URL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html
```

Comment: Thanks!!!, I am new to databases and didn't know it was a function.